# Physical or geometric meaning of the trace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, soft-question, physics

The geometric meaning of the determinant of a matrix as an area or a volume is dealt with in many textbooks. However, I don't know if the trace of a matrix has a geometric meaning too.

> Is there any geometric or physical (intuitive) significance related to
>   the trace of a matrix?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13526/geometric-interpretation-of-trace

Comment: Related question on Phys.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137158/2451

Comment: @Amzoti Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: @Qmechanic Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Amzoti and @Qmechanic suggested in the comments, the question has received satisfactory answers on [*MathOverflow*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13526/geometric-interpretation-of-trace) and [*Physics Stack Exchange*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137158/what-information-does-the-trace-of-a-matrix-give).